# 403 Forbidden Error when sending Content-Type application/json JSON body requests

Tags: php, .htaccess, lumen

I'm using AXIO to send a POST `application/json` content-type in the body of the request to an API service built with Lumen 6.x on PHP 7.4. However, My server gives me back a 403 Forbidden response( non json)

If I change the request content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with key=value content I get the expected 200 response

If I omit the content-type all together I get and error about not receiving the content values

If I use GET instead of POST I get the expected URL

the following is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
    </IfModule> 
    
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

This is my routes ...

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => ['cors'] ], function() use($router)
{
 $router->group(['middleware' => [ 'token', 'throttle:60', 'headers' ] ],function() use($router){
  ...
$router->post('test/{game_id}/score/create',['middleware' => ['throttle:6'], 'uses' => 'PlayerController@testPlayer']); });
});
```

actualy response

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
> use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

If I remove ALL middlewares it still has no affect.
If I change the route from `post` to `get` I get 200 response

Is it my .htaccess file or Lumen that is causing this?
What should I be looking for?